# Can I manage WSO2 components programatically?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Does WSO2 allow for management of components to be achieved programmatically? I'm hoping to do configuration management in an automated fashion for a multi-tenant deployment of Identity Server

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly you wanna configure programatically?

Comment: Are you expecting something like puppet to automate deployment, you can find sample puppet modules at https://github.com/wso2/puppet-modules which can be used to automate Identity Server and other WSO2 product deployments.